# save file without prompt window in flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm making an karaoke application in flash and I have a problem. when the client stops singing, I want this recording to saved in a specific folder on the server, without the prompt message. so far all the upload or download apps I made use `FileReference` , but it always had a prompt message. is there any way to save the song directly ? thanks in advance.

Comment: well I've seen some karaoke applications that save sound as you sing, like at :  [link](http://www.thekaraokechannel.com/online#) 
and it's made in flash. any suggestions on what  should I do?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question, you could look into adobe media server of red5 for some existing solutions (old comment deleted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.red5-recorder.com/ looks like a nice starting point

Comment: thank you. my company is considering buying a karaoke web application for further uses. any ideas on where to find these products? I googled high and low but wasn't able to find any

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you intend on saving a .wav file that you have recorded to the server.

```
// AS3 code
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest ( 'http://pathto/save.php' );
var loader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
request.contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
// bytes is your byteArray containing an encoded .wav file ready to save.
request.data = bytes;
loader.load( request );


//PHP code
$fp = fopen( 'filename.wav', 'wb' );
fwrite($fp, file_get_contents('php://input'));
fclose( $fp );
```